# read individual img src from folder contents into HTML

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to write some simple code, but I am not sure what to use, javascript or PHP.
I have some structured HTML docs and I want to insert an image from a folder into each img src attribute.
So basically I would need to read in the contents and then insert each one, one by one.

```
<div class="slideshow">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="main">
                        <a href="product1.html"><img src="images/sample/name1-1.jpg" alt="" width="630" height="400" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="second">
                        <img src="images/sample/name1-2.jpg" alt="" width="310" height="190" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="third">
                        <img src="images/sample/name1-3.jpg" alt="" width="310" height="190" />
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Thanks to anyone who might be able to steer me in the right direction..

I am using the following code to get the images from the directory

```
<?php

Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");

function returnimages($dirname=".") {
$pattern="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)"; 
$files = array();
$curimage=0;
if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ 

echo 'galleryarray['.$curimage.']="'.$file .'";';
$curimage++;
}
}

closedir($handle);
}
return($files);
}

echo 'var galleryarray=new Array();'; 
returnimages() 
?>
```

but at this point I am not sure how to insert each file name into the src attribute

Comment: Where do you get the image from?

Comment: the images are to be uploaded by the user, I then need to read their path into the source attr of the structured HTMl doc

Comment: you can make a table to hold the image name associated with a product id that the image is for and then store the images in a folder say for example "uploaded" then use the name from database and get the path as "images/uploaded/productImage001.jpg"

Comment: I should clarify, I need the user to upload a series of images for thier slideshow, then I need to take that uploaded folder contents and have it populate the HTML file whenever it is called, I might be going about this the wrong way :)

Comment: @Kaushtuv I think that solution might work, do you have an example of how I might do that?

Comment: your html, is it already written? or you want to create that slideshow tag by using list of images taken from directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here on how to upload image to floder using php here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Then Once you are done uploading simply write an insert query to add to your table containing image details such as image name and product id associated with it

```
INSERT INTO images (id, image_name, product_id) VALUES ('myimage.jpg', '20');
```

I am assuming that you use auto increment for 'id' field, the primary key for images.

Then you just query the images table by product_id and get the image name then add to the scr field as

```
$imagename = 'myimage.jpg';

<img src="images/<?=$imagename;?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

With PHP you could use the glob() function to get specific files from a directory.

For instance `glob("path/to/images/*.jpg")` would give you an array of the jpg images in your directory. Then you could use a foreach loop to print them all to a html page.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read a directory on the server with JavaScript, so you must use PHP, and something like RecursiveDirectoryIterator (http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)